# CSS Valign different line spans of text

Tags: tabs, vertical-alignment, css, valign

I am currently working on a tabbed layout for one my site's pages and im having a problem with aligning text vertically in different tabs since some of it spans one line and some spans two. I need to position the text in the middle of each tab, and not to have the text aligned by the first line.

I've tried Valign and Line-height so far but they are not very helpful.

Comment: Please post the code you need help with. Otherwise you'll get suggestions like try this and try that. With the code we can give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `vertical-align: middle`, but realize that in order for that to be applied you need to use `display: table-cell`.

For example, if you use something similar to this HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Some Text</span>
</div>
```

Then you could get the desired centering using:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkC5Z/) example.

​

Answer (score 0):

If you need the text centered both vertically and horizontally, use:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

`valign` is an HTML attribute for `td` elements, so it probably won't work on your "tabs"

Comment: I don't have any idea why but vertical-aling has no affect on the text whatsoever
height:32px;
                      text-align: center;
                       font-weight: bold;
                       font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                       font-size: 14px;
   min-height:2em;
                        padding-top: 12px;
this is what i have so far

Comment: @user1590687 If you post your HTML and CSS you're having trouble we can better help you center the text

Answer (score 0):

use line-height
ex)
line-height:20px

Comment: That will center the text in its line, but it will probably throw off the multi-line ones

Answer (score 0):

A really helpful read for this is [understanding vertical align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

I'm assuming you're talking about the label on each tab selector here. You could use one of the tricks from that page, and center your tab text by putting it in an inner container .

Off the top of my head, have you tried:
`line-height:100%;` ?
That might set the line height to the height of the parent, or it might fill the screen; not sure.